# Mirror equation for extended objects

Tags: optics, geometric-optics

[image]

Using this diagram author proves

$$\frac{1}{v}+\frac{1}{u}=\frac{1}{f}$$ --(1)

Then he uses this formula to find the location of the image for an extended object as shown here.

[image]

My doubt is that we proved equation (1) for a point object ,but then used it for an extended object.
Why is that true?

Comment: The lens formula is an approximation and works reasonably well when the angles of incidence are small.  Does this answer your question? [Why does a ray parallel to principal axis passes from focus after reflection from a concave mirror and vice a versa is also true? Why is it so?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/451702/why-does-a-ray-parallel-to-principal-axis-passes-from-focus-after-reflection-fro)